# Disallow img tag in comments?

Tags: images, comments

I have been looking quite a long time for a way to stop people from posting external images in comments i e

```
<img alt="my photo" src="http://example.co.uk/pic.jpg" />
```

and the image is displayed, without permission from the owner. This is hard coded somewhere in core but I can't find a way to unset this behaviour. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can strip images on display pretty easily.

```
add_filter(
  'comment_text',
  function($comment) {
    $allowed_html = array(
        'a' => array(
        'href' => array(),
        'title' => array()
      ),
      'br' => array(),
      'em' => array(),
      'strong' => array()
    );
    return  wp_kses($comment, $allowed_html);
  }
);
```

That will strip any tags not listed in the provided array. To specifically strip images with links to external sources you need something more complicated.

```
function strip_external_images($match) {
  if (empty($match)) return;
  $site = parse_url(get_site_url());
  $parsed = parse_url($match[1]);
  if (empty($parsed['host']) || $site['host'] !== $parsed['host']) {
    return '';
  } else {
    return $match[0];
  }
}

add_filter(
  'comment_text',
  function($comment) {
    $pattern = '|<img.*src="([^"]*)"[^>]+>|';
    return preg_replace_callback($pattern,'strip_external_images',$comment);
  }
);
```

That should allow users to add images to comments but only images hosted at same domain as the site itself.

Answer (score 0):

I added iframe to your first function to allow embeds from sites like youtube and instagram. I reckon that is a secure way? It works as intended now. I am not sure what your second function accomplishes, the end result is the same with or without it. Perhaps I wasn't clear enough about what I wanted to accomplish in my original question? Thank you very much. I will accept your answer.

```
add_filter(
'comment_text',
function($comment) {
$allowed_html = array(
    'a' => array(
        'href' => array(),
        'title' => array()
        ),
    'br' => array(),
    'em' => array(),
    'strong' => array(),
    'iframe' => array(
        'src' => array(),
        'height' => array(),
        'width' => array()
        ),
);
return  wp_kses($comment, $allowed_html);
}
);
```

Comment: The second block of code _should_ allow users to add images but ___only___ images hosted at your domain.